# Waveforms of the driver for a stepper motor

Tags: circuit-analysis

What signals are important in this circuit to be represented with time waveforms? Are just the output signals important? Where in the circuit should I measure all the important signals? Is the transient analysis the correct way to represent them in Micro-Cap?

[image]

Comment: May I assume IC1 is a CD4017? TP1 has a bypass around it and will not have that big impact. The 4 resistors at the FET gates should pull down the gates to GND if no diode feeds the gate.

Comment: What is your goal? Please realize that most modern stepper motors are bipolar and are designed to be driven with constant current.

Comment: The goal is just to make it work. Its a university project. Our mentor told us that its a good idea and that we should just try to get the waveforms, and i dont know which ones we should show him. Yes the IC1 is CD4017.

Comment: You should measure the ones you think are wrong, or the ones you just want to look at.

Comment: If you are going to connect to a real motor, you want to buy a unipolar motor that is designed to be driven with a constant voltage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a circuit that is new to you, the key is *baby steps*. This circuit has an obvious flow from left to right, your schematic is fairly good for a beginner (make the fix the Jens pointed out).

An experienced designer would probably only probe the 555 output and the MOSFET gates. If the gate signals were wrong, then they would troubleshoot by adding intermediate points.

A beginner should work more slowly. First check the 555 output. If it is working, then check the CD4017 outputs, then check the gate outputs, etc. Your circuit is fairly simple, so you can probably keep all the probe points active on your simulation. For more complicated circuits, you may want to remove intermediate probe points after you are convinced that that part of the circuit is working. Otherwise the simulation output can get very cluttered.